# Difference between $('.huyen') and $('.huyen')[0]

Tags: javascript, jquery

What are different between `$(".huyen")[0].style.opacity` and `$(".huyen").style.opacity`?

When I use console.log to print out value return of two statements:

`$(".huyen")[0]` ----> [object HTMLDivElement]

`$(".huyen")` -----> [object HTMLCollection]

I don't understand about having [0] and have not [0].

Can you explain for me about this problem?

Comment: `$('.x')` is a selector. `$('.x')[0]` is the first selected element, if any.

Comment: @Amadan yeah wasn't thinking properly... comment deleted

Comment: if `$(".huyen")` is giving you an `HTMLCollection` object you arent working with jquery.

Answer (score 4):

> When creating new elements (or selecting existing ones), jQuery returns the elements in a collection. Many developers new to jQuery assume that this collection is an array. It has a zero-indexed sequence of DOM elements, some familiar array functions, and a .length property, after all. Actually, the jQuery object is more complicated than that.

See More: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/

So when you call:

```
$(".huyen")
```

This represents a jQuery Object. That object has a number of elements within it. You can call the first element by the the `0` index:

```
$(".huyen")[0]
```

For example, when you use:

```
$(".huyen")[0].style.opacity = 0.95;
```

This allows you to access the DOM Elements and change the style. To do this in jQuery you can do:

```
$(".huyen").css("opacity", 0.95);
```

`.css()` is a specific function in the collection of that jQuery Object.

Answer (score 1):

`$(".huyen")` returns a reference to a jQuery object. `$(".huyen")[0]` references the first DOM node that the jQuery object holds in its collection of HTML elements (if any).